# Running 'runsbt' to compile a spark app results in java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to run 'runsbt' so that I can compile/package my spark application except that it results in the following error:

```
$ /home/blah/blah/scripts/runsbt
/home/blah/blah/scripts
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home17/blah/target/config-classes/$6d7552488da5a7237b89.cache (No such file or directory)
```

I checked the location mentioned and there is no $6d7552488da5a7237b89.cache present like the error states but how do I get past this error?

I did not delete the file and wasn't even aware of this location.

I am pretty new to scala/spark...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you do an `sbt clean`?

Comment: Previously I  have been able to run 'clean' by first running 'runsbt' and then I can run commands like 'clean', 'compile', 'package'. But now that runsbt is throwing an error I have not been able to run clean. Any other way to run clean that does not involve running runsbt?

Comment: Delete all "target" directories in all sub projects.

Comment: how did that work out?

Comment: @marios, thanks for the comment. Worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a very similar (possibly the same) issue.  The error occurred even when attempting the clean command, but manually deleting every target directory did work.